# Reduce the value of a vehicle every month

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, triggers

What I am trying to do is to reduce the value of every vehicle in the 'Vehicle' table so that when the date reaches one month past the 'LastUpdate' value the 'Value' column is reduced by 2.5%. The trigger should run AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE. The problem is, a DBA may not logon to the database every day, so if it is has been six months since the last logon, the trigger will loop through, reduce the value by 2.5% and do ADD_MONTHS(LastUpdate, 1).

My code for the function that will calculate the value is:

```
REATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  fn_Vehicle_Value
(VehicleNumber IN NUMBER,
VehicleValue IN OUT NUMBER)
RETURN NUMERIC
IS
BEGIN 
VehicleValue := VehicleValue - (VehicleValue * 0.025);
RETURN VehicleValue;
END;
/
```

This is my attempt at creating the system trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tg_VehicleDepreciate
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
IS
CURSOR vehicle_cur IS SELECT "VALUE", LastUpdate FROM Vehicle;
BEGIN
FOR vehicle_rec IN vehicle_cur LOOP

      WHILE LastUpdate < SYSDATE LOOP
           LastUpdate."Value" := fn_Vehicle_Update("VALUE");

            UPDATE Vehicle
             SET LastUpdate := ADD_MONTHS(LastUpdate, 1)
              WHERE Vehicle# = vehicle_cur.Vehicle#;

      END LOOP;


EXIT WHEN vehicle_cur%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP
END;
/
```

From what I can tell, my function is right. But the trigger does not compile and produces the following error report:

> Error report -
>   ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification
>   04079. 00000 -  "invalid trigger specification"
>   *Cause:    The create TRIGGER statement is invalid.
>   *Action:   Check the statement for correct syntax.

I am guessing it is a syntax error, but there may also be a logical error that I cannot work out.

Comment: Why not just create a view that calculates this "on the fly"? I don't see the need to create a trigger for something that can be derived from existing data (you would need a "start date" or "created date" in the `vehicle` table)

Comment: Its a uni assignment and I have to do exactly what I've been told. The tutor told us we need to use a function and a trigger.

Comment: Sounds a bit stupid to trigger your update by a `AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE` trigger. Why do you not create a `SCHEDULER JOB` and run this once every midnight for example?

Comment: Did your tutor jsut advice to use "a trigger" or a `AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE` trigger?

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW ERRORS` after compiling your trigger would reveal all errors.

Here are few..
1) in update, it is just `SET somecolumn = Somevalue`
2) oracle implicitly opens the cursor and closes to, when used with a FOR loop. 
3) after using FOR loop,the fetched results should be used like.. Forloopvariable.column-name
4) added `Vehicle#` to your cursor.
5) added  V_date logic.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tg_VehicleDepreciate
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
IS
CURSOR vehicle_cur IS SELECT "VALUE", LastUpdate ,Vehicle# FROM Vehicle;
V_date DATE;
BEGIN
FOR vehicle_rec IN vehicle_cur LOOP

      V_date := vehicle_rec.LastUpdate;

      WHILE   V_date < SYSDATE LOOP
          /* what are you trying here? */
           ---vehicle_rec."Value" := fn_Vehicle_Update("VALUE");

            UPDATE Vehicle
             SET LastUpdate = ADD_MONTHS(LastUpdate, 1)
              WHERE Vehicle# = vehicle_rec.Vehicle#;

             V_date := ADD_MONTHS( V_date,1);

      END LOOP;

END LOOP
END;
/
```